# Why did `git branch -D SomeOtherBranch` delete files on my current branch?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a project with several feature branches in development. In the process of consolidating updates, I merges branch B into branch A. Specifically, while checked out on A, I ran `git merge B`.
There were no merge conflict.
To be safe, I `git push`ed my repository to the remote, then `git pull`ed and `git status` as a sanity check.
To be clear I merged neither A nor B to master.
Now, while still on A, I ran `git branch -D B` to delete the merged branch (I don't need it anymore, right?).
Anyways, immediately after I ran `git status` to discover that several entire files were staged for deletion; including several files modified during the merge and more!
I can just reset or etc. to recover the files, I'm not worried about that; I just want to know what the hell happened!
Thanks in advance, please ask anything that isn't clear.

If it makes a difference, I am using git bash client on Win10.

Comment: It doesn't.  If some files were staged for deletion *after* `git branch -D B`, those files were staged for deletion *before* `git branch -D B` too. "Staged for deletion" just means *exist in the `HEAD` commit and do not exist in the index* and neither of these are touched by `git branch -d` or `git branch -D`.

Comment: @torek Sure that's what it _should_ be, although that's not what happened. The stage was empty before the `git branch -D B`, but after suddenly there were plenty of changes (deletions) ready to commit.

Comment: It's not the `git branch -D` that did it. Look for some other background task that modified the index, as that's the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a branch LOCALLY
Git will not let you delete the branch you are currently on so you must make sure to checkout a branch that you are NOT deleting. For example: git checkout master

Delete a branch with git branch -d .

For example: git branch -d fix/authentication

The -d option will delete the branch only if it has already been pushed and merged with the remote branch. Use -D instead if you want to force the branch to be deleted, even if it hasn't been pushed or merged yet.

The branch is now deleted locally.

Font: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/

Comment: This completely sidesteps the question I asked. 1. `git checkout A` 2. `git merge B` 3. `git status` (up to date) 4. `git branch -D B` 5. `git status` (files staged for deletion)....capisce?